# How do I apply any regex to my tagged text in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk, pos-tagger

I have a text. I tokenize it and remove stopwords. then I tag these words using stanford POS tagger in python. For now, I am using this code for tagging words and writing it in a file.

```
tag = nltk.pos_tag(filtered_sentence)
print("tagging the words")
fh = open("Stop_Words.txt", "w+")
for i in range(0,len(filtered_sentence)):
    fh.write((tag[i][0])+" "+(tag[i][1])+"\n")
fh.close()
```

Now I get a list something like this in my file:

```
paper NN
parallel NN
programming VBG
practical JJ
Greg NNP
Wilson NNP
intended VBD
scientist NN
interested JJ
... A big List ...
```

What I want to do now is to apply some Regex to this to find particular cases. For example, I want something like (JJ*N+) which means adjective followed by any noun. I did N+ because NN,NNP etc all are nouns.

How should I do this. I am clueless.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the `re` module?

Comment: Is this a python regex question?  Does it really have anything to do with `ntlk` or`pos-tagger`?  It rather sounds like you're trying to match particular strings such as `NN` `NNP` etc with regular expressions.

Comment: @timgeb i have looked into re module but i am not sure how to apply it to this problem. i know i can use re and try applying it to a sentence or something. But here in my file i have a word followed by a tag. I am not sure how to use it here.

Comment: Is JJ*N+ the only pattern you want?

Comment: @DanFarrell I got the result from the nltk module by tagging my words. I am not sure if the same module or anything related to that can be used here. Thats why i have tagged nltk as well. This sounds like a regex question to me. Although I am new I would appreciate if you could point out what I should tag. I will change it so that the question reaches the correct people.

Comment: @DanielMesejo For now yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want JJ*N you could do something like this:

```
import re

text = '''paper NN
parallel NN
programming VBG
practical JJ
Greg NNP
Wilson NNP
intended VBD
scientist NN
interested JJ
'''

pattern = re.compile('\w+? JJ\n\w+ NN.?', re.DOTALL)

result = pattern.findall(text)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['practical JJ\nGreg NNP']
```

**Explanation**

The pattern `'\w+? JJ\n\w+ NN.?'` matches a group of letters `\w+`, followed by a space followed by JJ followed by a `\n` followed by another group of letters followed by something with `NN` prefix. Note that I included both words because I think it might be useful for your purposes.

**UPDATE**

If you want zero or more adjectives `JJ*` followed by one or more nouns `NN+` you could do something like this:

```
import re

text = '''paper NN
parallel NN
programming VBG
practical JJ
Greg NNP
Wilson NNP
intended VBD
scientist NN
interested JJ
'''

pattern = re.compile('(\w+? JJ\n)*(\w+ NN\w?)+', re.DOTALL)

result = pattern.finditer(text)
for element in result:
    print(element.group())
    print('----')
```

**Output**

```
paper NN
----
parallel NN
----
practical JJ
Greg NNP
----
Wilson NNP
----
scientist NN
----
```

Comment: this is almost correct. except that it should give NN+ right.paper NN\nparallel NN should also satisfy this right? Even i was fiddling around with a regex like this '(\w+? JJ\n)*((\w+ NN.)+)' . I am not able to tell whether its correct or not. it gives "[(' ', 'paper NN\nparallel NN\n', 'parallel NN\n'), ('practical JJ\n', 'Greg NNP', 'Greg NNP'), ('', 'Wilson NNP', 'Wilson NNP'), (' ', 'scientist NN\n', 'scientist NN\n')]" as result. I feel i am going right but i cant quiet hit it correctly

Comment: I ran that regex in the text example and did not returned `paper NN parallel NN`, in fact it should not match it. Do you want to match `paper NN
parallel NN`?

Comment: okay sorry im noob in this. i just went to some interactive regex builder and was trying my luck there. Anyway when we are giving JJ*N+ , the N+ part should work right. The first two lines should form the output no?

Comment: JJ*N+ is not valid Python regex, the most close to that is `'JJ.+NN.'`

Comment: I mean. i want something like this: "zero or more adjectives followed by one or more nouns". I converted this sentence to JJ*N+. I wanted a regex for that sentence

Comment: @AbhijeetSridhar Updated the answer!

Comment: Perfect. I got my answer and I'm asking this question just for learning purposes. Shouldn't Line 1 and 2 be grouped as a single result? As it is one or more nouns. Does the regex work this way or is there an explanation for that .. Great answer by the way I'm so impressed :)

Comment: I you want them to be group do something like this:`pattern = re.compile('(\w+? JJ\n)*(\w+ NN\w?\n)+', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Lol are u god. I'm not even able to follow a single regex. I understand \w is for word. but then why + and ? is beyond me. I can understand the rest of the regex.  And this adding new line in the end was ingenious. i should have thought about it myself. U r really good at this